# QTreeView disable highlighting on a row hover

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qstylesheet

I don't want rows to be highlighted on mouse hover. How to disable this highlighting?

[image]

Either remove highlighting at all or change it's color: both solutions are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tView->setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item:hover{background-color:rgb(255,255,255);}");
```

Comment: change its color  in QTreeView item hover

Comment: `background-color:transparent` should also work, I think (in case the background isn't white or whatever might be a better option)

Comment: both above solutions hide an already selected item when you hover over it (Qt 5.9)....

Comment: The branch arrow still highlights on hover with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the Delegate way:

```
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class NoHighlightDelegate:public QStyledItemDelegate{
public:
    void initStyleOption(QStyleOptionViewItem*option,const QModelIndex&viewIndex)const override{
        QStyledItemDelegate::initStyleOption(option,viewIndex);
        option->state&=~QStyle::State_MouseOver;}
};
```

Then set this Delegate to your `QTreeView`:

```
//QTreeView*view;
auto*delegate=new NoHighlightDelegate();
delegate->setParent(view);
view->setItemDelegate(delegate);
```

And you will not get into the hidden selected line problem.